# Logical expression building out of a list of tuples

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

I am trying to build a logical expression out of that list of tuples (a,b) where a is an operator and b is depth. Basically if second element in next tuple is greater than previous one insert `'('` if less, insert `')'` - if equal skip.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

`lst = [('a', 8), ('or', 7), ('b', 8), ('and', 6), ('c', 7), ('and', 5), ('d', 7), ('and', 6), ('e', 7)]`

with desired output being:

```
((((((((a) or ( b)) and ( c)) and ((d) and (e)))))))
```

I have tried enumeration, looping while adding second list `lst[1:]` and so on but I am not able to get it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are the spaces around `or` and `and` necessary? They were not part of your data or description.

Answer (score 1):

Since you provide no code, I'll just give you some ideas without any final code. If you want more details, show more work of your own.

It seems that you need to compare the values of consecutive tuples. You also have nothing to compare before the first tuple or after the last tuple, but if you add tuples denoting empty item and depth 0 you can do all comparisons.

So in your loop, get two consecutive tuples using `zip` with lists that are one off from each other. You can add guard tuples at the beginning and at the end to show depth zero, and if their values are empty strings those values will not show in your result.

So you loop can be

```
for tuple1, tuple2 in zip([('', 0)] + lst, lst + [('', 0)]:
```

The first time through the loop, `tuple1` will be the guard tuple `('', 0)` and `tuple2` will be the first tuple in the list. The last time through the loop, `tuple1` will be the last tuple in the list and `tuple2` will be the guard tuple `('', 0)`. Every other time, `tuple1` is a tuple in your list and `tuple2` is the next tuple in your list.

Then when comparing tuples, add left or right parentheses depending on the difference between the depths. Those zero depths enable the beginning and the closing parentheses. After the parenthesis, add the item in the second (later) tuple. You can add spaces here if you like for `and` and `or`.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Hi Rory, yes the spaces were only there for readability purposes. I really like the approach - I will work on posting a snippet that follows it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about spaces around `and` and `or`, this code should work

```
def fun(lst):
    text = ''
    last = 0
    for op, depth in lst + [('', 0)]:
        if depth > last:
            text += '(' * (depth - last)
        elif depth < last:
            text += ')' * (last - depth)
        text += op
        last = depth
    return text
```

I think this is the correct understanding of your question, as it works for your example (minus spaces).

Comment: The code is basically just a translation of your description, but let me know if further comments would be useful.

Comment: Very instructive and easy to follow - the idea of splitting the original list and using it as the initial depth somehow escaped me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RoryDaulton Your comment made me look at the code again and try to make it cleaner, so I updated my post with cleaner code (I hope). When I was making the code the original time I was noticing the repetitiveness, but I couldn't come up with a nice way to avoid it. The new change I made to the way I include open parens is nice, but for closing parens (the `+ [('', 0)]` in the for loop), I would still like to make it better.

Comment: That update does indeed improve your code--it now meets the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. It remains simpler than my approach. Other than switching to my approach, which is better in some ways but worse in other ways, I don't see how to improve your code, other than adding comments. You did use one of my ideas, the guard tuple, but that's OK.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I see what you mean about the guard tuple in your post before mine, but I didn't see it, sorry. Thanks for being okay with it!